# How to use easings from this mini library?

Tags: javascript

https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/8231782

Ive found this pretty piece of code. Can someone explain to me how to use its easing helpers?

"A JavaScript Interval library that can play precisely timed intervals, and includes its own easing helpers."

```
(function () {
        'use strict';

        function Interval(listener, duration, speed) {
            var self = this;

            self.duration = duration;
            self.listener = listener;
            self.speed = speed;

            self.stop();
        }

        Interval.prototype = {
            constructor: Interval,
            play: function () {
                var
                self = this,
                timeStampA = +new Date();

                function interval(timeStamp) {
                    var
                    timeStampB = timeStamp || +new Date(),
                    intervalTime = timeStampB - timeStampA,
                    duration = self.duration,
                    currentTime = Math.min(self.currentTime + intervalTime, duration),
                    expectedTime = Math.min(intervalTime ? self.expectedTime + self.speed : self.expectedTime, duration) || 0,
                    speed = Math.max(self.speed + (expectedTime - currentTime), 0);

                    timeStampA = timeStampB;

                    self.currentTime = currentTime;
                    self.intervalTime = intervalTime;
                    self.expectedTime = expectedTime;
                    self.percentage = currentTime / duration || 0;

                    if (currentTime < duration) {
                        self.timeout = setTimeout(interval, speed);
                    }

                    self.listener.call(self);
                }

                interval(timeStampA);
            },
            pause: function () {
                var self = this;

                clearTimeout(self.timeout);
            },
            stop: function () {
                var self = this;

                self.pause();

                self.currentTime = 0;
                self.expectedTime = 0;
                self.intervalTime = 0;
                self.percentage = 0;
            }
        };

        Interval.easing = {
            linear: function (t) { return t; },

            easeIn: function (t, p) { return Math.pow(t, p); },
            easeOut: function (t, p) { return 1 - Math.pow(1 - t, p); },
            easeInOut: function (t, p) { var q = Math.pow(2, p) / 2; return t < 0.5 ? q * Math.pow(t, p) : -q * Math.pow(1 - t, p) + 1; },

            elasticIn:  function (t, p) { return Math.pow(p, 6 * (t - 1)) * -Math.sin((t - 1.075) * p * Math.PI / 0.3); },
            elasticOut: function (t, p) { return Math.pow(p, -6 * t) * Math.sin((t - 0.075) * p * Math.PI / 0.3) + 1; },
            elasticInOut: function (t, p) { var q = Math.pow(2, p) / 2; return t < 0.5 ? q * Math.pow(p, 6 * (t - 1)) * -Math.sin((t - 1.075) * p * Math.PI / 0.3) : -q * Math.pow(p, -6 * t) * Math.sin((t - 0.075) * p * Math.PI / 0.3) + 1; }
        };

        window.Interval = Interval;
    })();
```

Comment: Post code here, not behind links.

Comment: @Teepeemm done mate, have a look

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
function myFunction(){
 console.log("this will be repeated for example");
}
```

Then:

```
var myInterval = new Interval(myFunction, 1500, 20);
```

Example of use:

```
myInterval.play(); // Starts
myInterval.stop(); // Stops
```

Comment: How to use easings from this mini library?

Comment: @salmin this at most explains a setInterval nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I believe they are to be used like `var myInterval = new Interval(myFunction, 1500, Interval.easing.elasticIn(7, 2));` in the arguments (instead of writing a speed), but I'm not completly sure yet